# What is the ruby equivalent of this java loop since there's no pre-increment operator?

Tags: java, ruby

I have a java while loop that pre-increments the variable *i* everytime it checks the conditional in the while.

```
int i = low;
int a[] = new int[5];

while (less(a[++i], a[low]))
  if (i == hi) break;
```

How do you mimic this in Ruby?  Is it even possible?

Comment: I can do `while (less(a[i+=1], a[low]))` which is a post increment I think, but is not a pre-increment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is different, but you can certainly reproduce the logic:

```
loop do
  i += 1
  break if (!less(a[i], a[low])) || (i == hi)
end
```

I'm assuming that `a`, `low`, `hi`, and `i` have all been properly initialized somewhere before this, as I assume they were in your Java as well even though you didn't show it.  I'm also assuming that `less` is a method implemented elsewhere that returns a boolean result.

Comment: Yes, thanks for building in the assumptions, that's what I was looking for!